# Meteor - is it possible to get current url from any browser and check it against a local database?

Tags: meteor

I am looking for ideas on how to approach making a simple Meteor mobile app that checks every url the user visits against a local database.

The app should run silently in the background and trigger a notification when the user visits a page in the local database.

1. Can Meteor get the current url from any device/browser?
2. Does it exist any relevant projects that I can build on?

Comment: what do you mean 'get current url' ? and what exactly are you going to check there

Comment: I mean to see which domain/url the user is currently visiting in their browser (no matter which browser they use). It may sound intrusive, but I would only like to check it against a list of domains stored in a local database and give the user a notification if it is listed. I do not want the users browsing history, just the "current url". Hope that's a bit more clear. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I guess this is what firewall apps and adblockers do. They check the loaded domains against a list in the phones local storage. Kind of what I would like to do -- but I don't want to block anything, just to give the user a notification. And I'd like to use Meteor to build the app.